# How can I filter my source dataset to copy only specific vaules to my sink?

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have a csv file with 2 columns (id and name). The csv file has over 1 million names. I'm struggling to workout how I can filter my results to only copy data where column 2 has the name 'mary' in it.

Can anyone advise?

Answer (score 0):

Add a Data Flow activity to your ADF pipeline. In that pipeline, point the Source to your CSV dataset. Next, add a Filter transformation and write an expression such as name == 'mary'. Next, add a Sink. This will copy only rows that have 'Mary' for the value in the name column.